# Call js from within h:dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I'm trying to use the count up feature of a script found [here](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) inside of a `<h:dataTable>`

Using JSF, I have an `<h:dataTable>` which displays timestamps from a database (this works). For each column, I want to display the timestamp and the time passed since that timestamp (using the script). I have the library loaded correctly but the counting is never displayed. I'm trying to use jquery as suggested.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="_item">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Column 1"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="_item.alertTime"/>
        <div id="timethis">
        </div>
        <rich:jQuery name="timerstuff"
                     selector="#timethis" 
                     query="$(#localform\\:timethis).countdown({since: _item.alertTime});">
        </rich:jQuery>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: Show the generated markup. people shouldn't have to parse server code in their heads for a client side problem that is occurring in the html/javascript

Comment: Also identify if errors are thrown, not easy to see where `_item.alertTime` will get defined in script

Comment: Have you tried observing the generated HTML code and the browser console? There should be some parse errors especially in the `query` attribute.

Comment: I will check these and post.  Was also my mistake leaving out my intended question to ask: Am I even using jQuery statement correctly?  I've tried to find examples in the docs and elsewhere but had trouble.

Comment: Console shows: SyntaxError: Illegal character
packed.js:1

this file is part of richfaces resources so there is probably something wrong with my query syntax.